# Post content only visible when only logged with admin

Tags: php, wordpress

Check live- http://mylistoflists.com/9-football-season-snack-ideas/

Post content only visible when i logged with admin, due to my low knowledge on wordpress i am not sure how to fix that.

**N: B: Post visibility set as PUBLIC!**

**Without Admin**

[image: Without Admin]

**With Admin**
[image: With Admin]

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your post is set to Private in the Post settings in the posts tab on your dashboard.

You have to click on edit and then choose public instead.

[image]

**EDIT:**

First Look at your trashcan. If there are posts with the same name it can conflict with the new post. Try to empty your trashcan.

Second: Are you using a cache plugin? Try to disable this and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Hmm. are you using a plugin called Recent Category Posts? If so try to deactivate it and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Don't have any plugin called "Recent Category Posts", deactivate "W3 Super Cache" not works, also make a test post with new name that not works too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also checked your trashcan?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49641/discussion-between-arifix-and-kees-sonnema)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Only Admin can see your code:
> ```

```
<?php if(current_user_can('administrator')): ?>

//put your code part only admin can see


<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem will solve with one these of solutions:

1. first check that post published in public mode.
2. if you have a cach plugin or any speed boost plugin, first deactive that plugin and see that problem resolved or not?
3. if above solution not work, then deactive all plugins of wordpress and check again,
4. and also if above solution not work, change your wordpress theme to default theme like twenty seveteen and check that problem solved or not

Answer (score -1):

Deactivate "W3 Super Cache" Plugin or any cache Plugin. It works for me. Hopefully, it will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

DELETE htaccess file, is the only 100% working solution.